# Unable to find Directory name

Tags: c#, .net, window

I wanted to get directory name from path, but it returns the following error :

> The directory name is invalid

the following are example path:

> strFilePathName = C:\inetpub\wwwroot\PSSWeb\foldername\xxx.ini

the following code I use to get `Directoryname` based on prefix PSS and its should return PSSWeb. I'm unable find solution for this.

```
var directories = Directory.GetDirectories(strFilePathName,
                                           "PSS?",
                                           SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @Nasreddine "The directory name is invalid"

Comment: strFilePathName  is not directory name it is file name

Comment: var directories = Directory.GetDirectories(Directory.GetParent(strFilePathName).FullName,"PSS?",SearchOption.AllDirectories);

Comment: Directory.GetParent(strFilePathName) its return the wrong path ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the path name you have specified "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\PSSWeb\foldername\xxx.ini" is not a directory but a file.

```
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Returns the names of the subdirectories (including their paths) that match the
    //     specified search pattern in the specified directory, and optionally searches
    //     subdirectories.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   path:
    //     The relative or absolute path to the directory to search. This string is not
    //     case-sensitive.
    //
    //   searchPattern:
    //     The search string to match against the names of subdirectories in path. This
    //     parameter can contain a combination of valid literal and wildcard characters
    //     (see Remarks), but doesn't support regular expressions.
    //
    //   searchOption:
    //     One of the enumeration values that specifies whether the search operation should
    //     include all subdirectories or only the current directory.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     An array of the full names (including paths) of the subdirectories that match
    //     the specified criteria, or an empty array if no directories are found.
    //
    // Exceptions:
    //   T:System.ArgumentException:
    //     path is a zero-length string, contains only white space, or contains one or more
    //     invalid characters. You can query for invalid characters by using the System.IO.Path.GetInvalidPathChars
    //     method.-or- searchPattern does not contain a valid pattern.
    //
    //   T:System.ArgumentNullException:
    //     path or searchPattern is null.
    //
    //   T:System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException:
    //     searchOption is not a valid System.IO.SearchOption value.
    //
    //   T:System.UnauthorizedAccessException:
    //     The caller does not have the required permission.
    //
    //   T:System.IO.PathTooLongException:
    //     The specified path, file name, or both exceed the system-defined maximum length.
    //     For example, on Windows-based platforms, paths must be less than 248 characters
    //     and file names must be less than 260 characters.
    //
    //   T:System.IO.IOException:
    //     path is a file name.
    //
    //   T:System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException:
    //     The specified path is invalid (for example, it is on an unmapped drive).
    public static string[] GetDirectories(string path, string searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption);
```

thats the documentation  of the method. It is mentioned that the first parameter must be a directory.

Comment: Great ,the error gone , but its cannot find the prefix in directory name as in searchpattern , you know what could be the problem?

Comment: use PSS* instead of PSS? and also it would find files within the subdirectories and onto the parent directory.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the result as i wanted with using quite different method from above , which is  as following :

```
string strFilePathName = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\PSSWeb\foldername\xxx.in";
string x = Path.GetDirectoryName(strFilePathName);
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@x);
DirectoryInfo OneLevelsUp = dir.Parent;
```

the Result i got `PSSWeb` folder name from the path `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\PSSWeb\foldername\xxx.ini`.

**To get two level folder name**

if anyone want to get two level up you may try following line ,
just change to

```
 DirectoryInfo OneLevelsUp = dir.Parent 
 DirectoryInfo TwoLevelsUp = dir.Parent.Parent
```

it will return `wwwroot` folder name according to the path mentioned above